# slide container with webform accessible

Tags: css, forms, containers, accessibility, slidingdrawer

I am a bit new to the accessible topic and want to learn a bit more. I have build a small project where I have the information/articles, webforms in "drawers" on the left side. They are closed in the beginning and open when I hover or focus the drawer. (like the browser tabs, but on the left side of the container)

The tabbing is ok, i reach all elements, including the webform.

But then, when I tab to the webform element inside the drawer closes, of course - because I no longer focus the drawer it self.

Is there a way without javascript to hold it open while tabbing the webform inside the drawer?

```css
.form {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #aaa;
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  transition: 1250ms;
  transform: translateX(-517px);
  max-width: 100%;
}

.form:hover,
.form:focus,
.form:active {
  transform: none;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.article2 {
  border-color: #00b7ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="article2 form" tabindex="5">
  <h3>Kontaktforms</h3>
  <form>
    <h2>Kontakta oss</h2>
    <label for="name">Namn</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" tabindex="6" required />

    <label for="email">E-postadress</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" tabindex="7" required />

    <label for="message">Meddelande</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" tabindex="8" required></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Skicka" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I don't think you can do this without Javascript. You effectively want to change the CSS properties of the drawers based on whether one of their descendants is focused - and there's no way of doing that in pure CSS.

Comment: PS since you obviously care about accessibility - and good on you for that, too many developers don't - you should know that you shouldn't be using positive `tabindex` values, as these can cause the tab key to focus elements in an unexpected order. Just stick with `tabindex="0"` if you need to make something keyboard-focusable that isn't by default - here you are adding it to textareas and inputs, both of whch are tabbabale anyway, so there is no need for any tabindex attribute to be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:focus-within` seems to work. I tried your example and added `:focus-within` to the other focus states.

```
<style>
.form:hover,
.form:focus,
.form:focus-within,
.form:active {
  transform: none;
  z-index: 9999;
}
</style>
```

Also, as @RobinZigmond commented, don't use `tabindex` **except** on your `<div>`, and only use `tabindex="0"`.

However, by making your `<div>` a focusable element, it will also need a `role` and a label (eg, `aria-label`). But that also means your `<div>` is an interactive element, which it really isn't.  The only reason you have `tabindex` on your `<div>` is so you can specify a `focus` attribute in CSS.  But with `focus-within`, you no longer need to have focus on your `<div>` so you can remove the `tabindex` from your `<div>` **and** you can remove the `focus` CSS attribute from your form.

The final code just changes `focus` to `focus-within`:

```
.form:hover,
.form:focus-within,
.form:active {
  transform: none;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

And I removed `tabindex` from all the inputs and the div.

```
<div class="article2 form">
  <h3>Kontaktforms</h3>
  <form>
    <h2>Kontakta oss</h2>
    <label for="name">Namn</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />

    <label for="email">E-postadress</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />

    <label for="message">Meddelande</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Skicka" />
  </form>
</div>
```

And one final accessibility comment. Your `<div>` has a medium gray background and your input labels are light gray. That makes for a 1.4:1 contrast ratio which is below the 4.5:1 minimum for accessibility.